# Doctrine merge error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Slim Framework, Doctrine and Twig for a small application. Everything works perfect until I tried storing an entity in a session.

```
Type: ErrorException
Code: 4096
Message: Object of class Doctrine\Models\PeopleGlobal\Code could not be converted to string
File: /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Log.php
Line: 309
Trace

#0 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Log.php(309): Slim\Slim::handleErrors(4096, 'Object of class...', '/var/www/app/ve...', 309, Array)
#1 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Log.php(203): Slim\Log->log(7, Object(Doctrine\Models\PeopleGlobal\Code), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/index.php(36): Slim\Log->info(Object(Doctrine\Models\PeopleGlobal\Code))
#3 [internal function]: Doctrine\Models\PeopleGlobal\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(462): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1326): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#7 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#8 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#9 /var/www/app/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1271): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#10 /var/www/html/index.php(115): Slim\Slim->run()
#11 {main}
```

The exception is thrown on the following line: "$code = $entityManager->merge($code);"

```
if (isset($_SESSION['code']) && $_SESSION['code'] instanceOf Code) {
  $app->log->info("Event: Session contains code.");

  $code = $_SESSION['code'];
  $code = $entityManager->merge($code);

  $global_event = $code->getGlobalEvent();

  $app->render('event.html', array(
    'global_event' => $global_event,
    'code' => $code
  ));
}
```

Looking forward to some help? Any other information you require?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `Doctrine\Models\PeopleGlobal\Code` has a `__toString()` method?

Comment: @AlbertoFernández, your comment is correct, however Doctrine should merges objects without using `__toString()` function.

Comment: It does not have a __toString() method, but I don't think merge() is supposed to use __toString()

Comment: I checked and the __toString() method does not solve the issue. The Code entity contains 2 foreign keys (event, visitor), is there anything I need to do or configure in order to do the detach()?